# thinking sphinx search on child model property

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I'm trying thinking sphinx in my rails app and it seems I have a problem with indexing my data.

I have a parent model which has many properties:

```
class Parent
  has_many :childs
end

class Property
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

Properties has keys and values in database, and I want to find all Parent objects which has at least one child with given key-value pair. How I can build index for Parent model in this case?

I'll be very grateful if you can help.

Answer (score 1):

In the define_index block you can call attributes of children.

```
define_index do
 ...
 indexes children(:attr) as children_attrs
end
```

With that you should be able to index what you need.

Although in your example there does not seem to be a connection between Parent and Property, so there would have to be one for this to work. Also the key value pair, are those being stored as a hash, or are you referring to the attributes?